# Heroku push gets rejected

Tags: git, heroku

I am having problem in pushing my master branch to heroku. I am using the following command:

```
git push heroku master
```

Error that I am encountering-

```
Counting objects: 114, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (112/112), done.
Writing objects: 100% (114/114), 335.40 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 114 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
remote: More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:

remote: !       Push rejected to skyconfapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/skyconfapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/skyconfapp.git'
```

I even visited Heroku's link https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure  and tried to implement every method that they have mentioned but nothing seems to be working for me.

Can someone please assist?

Comment: Can you use an alternative buildpack? There does appear to be a file at the failed link, but Heroku is failing to add it to the app. There may be a problem with that particular buildpack.

Comment: Tried doing that also but still getting the same buildpack error. @Deborah

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku push getting rejected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39242214/heroku-push-getting-rejected)

Comment: What happens when you try and set it through the Heroku UI?

Answer (score 15):

Just happened to me and then I got this working

Try clearing the buildpacks, adding it again and add/commit/push to heroku

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/php
git add/commit/push heroku master
```

Comment: heroku buildpacks:clear did it for me, nice one thanks!

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks Heruko provides different buildpacks for different languages(python,java,ruby ...)

Answer (score 8):

I got the same issue, but i fixed by adding "`requirements.txt`" in the root directory as mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#activation-1)

The Heroku Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a requirements.txt or Pipfile in the root directory. Even if an application has no module dependencies, it should include an empty requirements.txt or Pipfile to document that your app has no dependencies.

Comment: This was my problem as well. git initialized in a parent directory but I had all my important files in a subfolder. Moving requirements.txt(or pipfile) to root solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to push a nodejs app and you are getting this error, this could be because you are not specifying node version. I was having this error and it was being caused because I was not specifying "engines": { "node: "8.2.1" }

You can have more details here: https://kb.heroku.com/why-is-my-node-js-build-failing-because-of-an-invalid-semver-requirement

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when my Node.js app did not follow the buildpack requirements.  I had the package.json file in a /server subdirectory, but it needed to be at the root directory.  Once I moved all my server files into the root directory, heroku was able to determine the correct buildpack and I was able to push to my heroku app.

Answer (score 1):

for node users make sure there is only one file that satisfies the files of package-lock.json , I had a problem with the same issue and it was because i had npm-shrinkwrap.json file and package-lock.json file as well i had to delete package-lock.json and the build succeded

Answer (score 0):

Late answer. Perhaps it can be helpful for a few.

That happened to me when I was pushing a python app. It can be caused if there's an error in naming some file. In my case, it's python and I had misspelled a file name. So, it was unable to detect the build pack. Renaming the file should work I guess.

Answer (score 0):

One cannot push random repos to Heroku without configuring some things in the app's root. For instance, if you want to make a Python app you should include a `requirements.txt` or `setup.py` file to your app's root. With this, Heroku can decide what kind of assests it needs and configure itself. And you can push successully from here.

The problem is mostly caused by a un-collectable dependency lib; check your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this is caused because when you create your frontend application, it also initialize git automatically.

First, you have to delte `.git` folder inside you *clientFolder* folder

Then, run the next code to delete the git submodule cache

```
git rm -f --cached clientFolder
```

Then just make an add and a commit to your repository

```
git add .
git commit -am 'Adding clientFolder to the main git repository'
```

Now you can run:

```
git push heroku master
```

Hope this would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue in Rails when I failed to run `bundle install` after removing a meaningless gem from my `Gemfile`. Consequently, `Gemfile.lock` was mismatched, and Heroku rejected the push.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error on a Javascript project by having 2 lock files. Heroku won't allow that.

After deleting `yarn.lock`, the error was solved.

Answer (score 0):

1- Your Project Must have **Procfile**
2- Your Project Must have a **requirements.txt** || Use ***pip freeze > requirements.txt*** command

This error is mainly raised due to the missing Procfile & requirements.txt files. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the requirement file needed a more up to date Python version. So I just used Python 3.10.0. When I finished with that, I was still having some issues pushing. But after re-reading the Heroku documentation I followed these steps:

```
git init
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/python
heroku git:remote -a <app_name>
git add .
git commit -am "make it better"
git push heroku master
```