# using deploy terminal heroku from file to server

Tags: heroku

[image]

problem on the photo.
**when i use the** `git push heroku master` terminal allways give me this response.
i search on google but i didn't find any qestion on my language.
i follow all codes but i see this.

```
heroku login
$ cd my-project/
```

$ git init
$ heroku git:remote -a afbchatapp
and

```
$ git add .
```

$ git commit -am "make it better"
$ git push heroku master
enter code here

Answer (score 0):

What language are you using?

Let's start with the problem at the beginning. Usually, Heroku tries to automatically detect the type of app you deploy by looking for certain files that act as signatures for the language you're using. So for example if it's a NodeJS app and you're deploying from Github, Heroku will look for the `package.json` file in the `main` branch. You can find the rest of the information for other files [here](https://help.heroku.com/1MC2J0GF/why-does-my-app-fail-to-detect-a-buildpack). You may want to look at this first.

From there [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39267808/heroku-push-gets-rejected) solution to an almost similar problem should be able to fix the push.

Comment: python only python